# class not found if included from extern

Tags: php, class

I have a this folder structure:

```
+ inc
++ functions.php
++ vendor

+ private
++ carddav
+++ check.php
```

my check.php looks like this and works:

```
<?php

require '../../inc/functions.php';

// CardDAV API
require '../../inc/vendor/autoload.php';

use MStilkerich\CardDavClient\{Account, AddressbookCollection, Config};
use Psr\Log\{AbstractLogger, NullLogger, LogLevel};
use Sabre\VObject\Component\VCard;
                    
class StdoutLogger extends AbstractLogger {
    public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()) {
        if ($level !== LogLevel::DEBUG) {
            $ctx = empty($context) ? "" : json_encode($context);
            echo ">>> ".$message . $ctx . "<br />";
        }
    }
}

Config::init(new StdoutLogger());
$account = new Account(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$abook = new AddressbookCollection(URL, $account);

$vcard =  new VCard();


?>
```

But now I would like to outsource this part into my functions.php:

**functions.php**

```
<?

    // CardDAV API
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use MStilkerich\CardDavClient\{Account, AddressbookCollection, Config};
    use Psr\Log\{AbstractLogger, NullLogger, LogLevel};
    use Sabre\VObject\Component\VCard;
                        
    class StdoutLogger extends AbstractLogger {
        public function log($level, $message, array $context = array()) {
            if ($level !== LogLevel::DEBUG) {
                $ctx = empty($context) ? "" : json_encode($context);
                echo ">>> ".$message . $ctx . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    
    Config::init(new StdoutLogger());
    $account = new Account(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    $abook = new AddressbookCollection(URL, $account);
?>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php

require '../../inc/functions.php';
$vcard =  new VCard();

?>
```

But now I get this error when I open the check.php:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VCard' not found in check.php:26
```

Where is my mistake?
Tank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports using `use` statement work on a per file basis. I.e. classes need to be imported in the file where they're used. In your case remove `Sabre\VObject\Component\VCard` import from `functions.php` and move it to `check.php` where `VCard` class is actually used.